# Проблемы с webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий код:

```
using (WebBrowser brows = new WebBrowser())
{
brows.Navigate(new Uri(this.url));
richTextBox1.Text = brows.DocumentText.ToString();
}
```

Однако, brows.DocumentText ничего не содержит.
На форме нет ни одного браузера. Как исправить проблему?

Comment: > На форме нет ни одного браузера.

Хм, а откуда они обычно там появляются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте события загрузки веб-страницы.

```
brows.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(brows_DocumentCompleted);
brows.Navigate(new Uri("http://google.ru", UriKind.Absolute));
while (brows.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

void brows_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = (sender as WebBrowser).Document.Body.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

На форме ничего и не будет, учитывая конструкцию using. Вы же правда понимаете зачем её используете?

Страница как минимум ещё не успела загрузиться.

Если Вам нужен именно Webbrowser на форме, положите его туда (либо из Toolbox перенесите, либо в коде

```
var web = new WebBrowser
Controls.Add(web);
```

Если же просто нужно скачать содержимое по URL, то лучше воспользуйтесь WebClient. [DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xz398a3f.aspx)